# How to use Pygubu - Python

Tags: python, tkinter, python-idle, pygubu

I am trying to use pygubu from the first time to make better GUI's. I have installed it using pip and it has installed correctly. However when I try and run the example code [Here (At the bottom of the web page)](https://pypi.org/project/pygubu/) I get the error

> AttributeError: module 'pygubu' has no attribute 'Builder'

I don't know if this code is correct or not. I have looked for ways to use this tool but all I can find are links and videos for installing it. I have also tried [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wuzV9P8geDg&feature=youtu.be) but can't figure out how to open/run/use. I am using python-idle if that is the issue. The code (if you don't want to follow the link) is:

```
# helloworld.py
import tkinter as tk
import pygubu


class HelloWorldApp:

    def __init__(self):

        #1: Create a builder
        self.builder = builder = pygubu.Builder()

        #2: Load an ui file
        builder.add_from_file('helloworld.ui')

        #3: Create the mainwindow
        self.mainwindow = builder.get_object('mainwindow')

    def run(self):
        self.mainwindow.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = HelloWorldApp()
    app.run()
```

I would appreciate any help. Also when I try installing it again - just to check - I get:

[image: My cmd]

Comment: What's the name of your python file?

Comment: make sure your file is not called `pygbu.py` so it doesn't import itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pygubu is an application. Find it in files from C: drive. The code:

```
# helloworld.py
import tkinter as tk
import pygubu


class HelloWorldApp:

    def __init__(self):

        #1: Create a builder
        self.builder = builder = pygubu.Builder()

        #2: Load an ui file
        builder.add_from_file('helloworld.ui')

        #3: Create the mainwindow
        self.mainwindow = builder.get_object('mainwindow')

    def run(self):
        self.mainwindow.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = HelloWorldApp()
    app.run()
```

Is run after you have created your UI (The format that this application uses) and that the name of the UI specified is helloworld.ui.

> Note that instead of helloworld.ui in the following line:
>
> builder.add_from_file('helloworld.ui') You should insert the filename
>   (or path) of your just saved UI definition.
>
> Note also that instead of 'mainwindow' in the following line:
>
> self.mainwindow = builder.get_object('mainwindow') You should have the
>   name of your main widget (the parent of all widgets), otherwise you
>   will get an error similar to the following:
>
> Exception: Widget not defined.

[This link explains the usage better than one stated in question](https://libraries.io/pypi/pygubu)

Comment: Does this answer your own question? Have you found the problem?

Comment: Yes @ChristianK.

Comment: Then mark it as answer please. Nevertheless I don't get how the AttributeError can be related to a missing `.ui` file.

Comment: I know - I just didn't understand how to use Pygubu @ChristianK. .I know how to use it now. Also I can accept my own answer in 22 hours.